# How to type hint $ctrl in AngularJS component template for WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

Is there any way to tell WebStorm which type `$ctrl` is in an AngularJS (v1) component HTML template file?

If it were a JavaScript file, I could use JSDoc, and WebStorm would use that information, and would detect correctly unused methods, etc.

WebStorm's documentation tells about Angular plugin, but that plugin doesn't seem to work with newer AngularJS components, only with older `ng-controller` style.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/11/webstorm-2018-3/) for WebStorm 2018.3, this was resolved.

> **AngularJS improvements**
>
> We know that many people still use AngularJS.
>   This is why we’ve fixed the top-voted problem affecting AngularJS
>   support in WebStorm: completion and resolve for `$ctrl`, or for the
>   name defined using the `controllerAs` property in the template.

So, if you have not updated WebStorm recently, I would first try that.

Otherwise, there is a hacky way to handle this. You could do something like this in an `ngInit` directive in your template:

```
<div ng-init="$ctrl=$ctrl"></div>
```

That should do the trick. But it's probably an ugly workaround. I would first try updating if you haven't done so recently.

Comment: Nice. I had not noticed, although I was already using it.

Webstorm 2018.3 seems to bring some support for `$ctrl` inside their own directives like ng-if, but it's still not working for custom user defined components and their attributes bindings inside the template.

Also doesn't work for jump to defination over the method name, even though jump does indeed work on the `$ctrl` itself.

Comment: @jheusala You might want to check out the [issue tracker filtered for AngularJS](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WEB?q=%23AngularJS%20) for WebStorm. I use WebStorm and AngularJS as well, and sometimes I've found some decent workarounds for functionality not yet implemented in WebStorm.